# Scrape Instagram by hashtags - using Python

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, instagram-api

I checked the standard API and it just gives the images and videos for a particular hashtag.

No user personal information.

I need the Instagram post location.

I want to extract the location where the Instagram post was posted.

For example, I want to explore the #coronavirus hashtag

The link will be

https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/coronavirus/

Then I want to get the following information

1.location of the post

2.image or video

3.Date posted
For each Instagram post.

I need at least the above 3 fields..

I checked FB's

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search/#getting-media-tagged-with-a-hashtag

The standard API will give me the image or the video. I don't think it provides the location of the Instagram post.

How to accomplish the above? I don't think standard API's doesn't help much.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much speed do you need. You could certainly get hrefs of the posts, then loop thru them. The location is in href containing href="/explore/locations and the time is in this time element:

```
<time class="_1o9PC Nzb55" datetime="2020-08-19T06:14:42.000Z" title="Aug 19, 2020">2 hours ago</time>
```

Depends on what time format and accuracy are you looking for